# Screen width detection with Javascript / jQuery - Sidebar to Tabbed Pullout

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a responsive design, with selectable sidebar data drawn from a database. At a screen width less than 751 pixels, that sidebar becomes a pull-out tab on the left of the screen. I cannot feasibly reload the data on state change (sidebar to tab or vice versa) as the amount of data is extensive. So, the solution seems to be using the tabbed state (using MB Extruder - a "hidden" tab utility) as the sidebar, also, and just changing the state of the div. However, that cannot be done without javascript as, in the sidebar state, Extruder needs to be open, whereas it needs to be closed when in the tab state.

So, I am doing the following to set the sidebar/tab:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    CheckScreen();
},
$(window).resize(function()
{
    CheckScreen();
}));
function CheckScreen()
{
    var ww=$(window).width();
    if(ww < 751)
    {
        $('#extruderLeft').closeMbExtruder();
        $('.extruder.left .flap').css('display', 'block'); // The tab
        $('.site_wrapper').css('padding-left', '30px');
    }
    else
    {
        $('#extruderLeft').openMbExtruder(true);
        $('.extruder.left .flap').css('display', 'none');
        $('.site_wrapper').css('padding-left', '0px');
    }
}
```

This changes the state from a sidebar column to a hidden state with a small tab on the left side of the screen when the screen width is less that 751 pixels. This will work fine at any size screen on document.ready. It will adjust fine when dragging the side of a browser from larger to smaller. However, when dragging back out to a larger width, the div will, rather randomly, switch from one state to another.

Perhaps there is a better way to do this altogether. If worse came to worse, I could have two separate entities (sidebar and tabbed state) holding the same data, and just use CSS, but that would be ridiculously redundant.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle? Hard to understand what you're asking.

Comment: I could, but to make it an exact reproduction would not be possible. I am editing my example above to (hopefully) provide a better explanation. The question mainly involves the method used to change the state of the div on change of screen size.

Comment: As far as this code goes it looks like it should work, maybe something in `openMbExtruder()` triggers the change back

Comment: **Sidenote:** In the if-clause, check `if ($('.extruder.left .flap').css('display')!='block') {` first (and in the second if-clause check for `'none'` obviously), otherwise everything inside the if-clause gets executed on every pixel resized

Comment: **Sidenote:** Also, this would be far more efficient: `$(window).load(function(){ $(window).resize(function(){ if($(window).width()<751){...}else{...} }).resize(); });` That way you don't have to create a named function AND call it twice. Maybe you need to indent it correctly to understand, but I can't do that in a comment so that's up to you. (I always put **window.resize** inside **window.load** instead of **document.ready** because if you need to scale thing that only works properly after **load** anyway, but for your purpose both will work).

Comment: @myfunkyside Please put this down as an answer so I can check it off as answered. That is exactly the problem. The way I did it was if(($('.extruder.left .flap').css('display')!='block') && ww < 751) and then changed the else to else if with == block as the argument. This is not working on load or refresh, but that should be an easy fix.

Comment: These days this actually is possible with CSS only (for changing the `display` state anyway: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp. Check out that first example on that page, you can change it into: `@media screen and (max-width:751px) { .extruder.left .flap {display:block;} }`

Comment: The reason I had to use javascript is the Extruder had to be told to open when in sidebar mode and close when in tab mode. All else is css and could, of course, be handles by media queries,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seemed to be faulty conditions in the if-clauses (see comments under the question).

This should do the trick:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() < 751) {
      if ($('.extruder.left .flap').css('display') != 'block') {
        $('#extruderLeft').closeMbExtruder();
        $('.extruder.left .flap').css('display','block'); // The tab
        $('.site_wrapper').css('padding-left','30px');
      }
    } else if ($('.extruder.left .flap').css('display') != 'none') {
      $('#extruderLeft').openMbExtruder(true);
      $('.extruder.left .flap').css('display','none');
      $('.site_wrapper').css('padding-left','0');
    }
  }).resize();
});
```

Notice the extra if-clauses checking the display-state:
`if ($('.extruder.left .flap').css('display') != 'block') {`
and
`} else if ($('.extruder.left .flap').css('display') != 'none') {`

This makes sure the sidebar/tab-switch only occurs on the break point of the specified screen-width, and the if-clauses aren't unnecessarily executed.

---

*I also changed your script a bit to make more efficient use of jQuery. This way you don't have to create a named function AND call it twice. (I always put `window.resize` inside `window.load` instead of `document.ready` because if you need to scale things that only works properly after `load` anyway, but for your purpose both will work.)*

Comment: @RationalRabbit I couldn't understand precisely what you did that didn't work, as opposed to what I did that did work, and if my solution worked perfectly without any other changes. If I forgot something just post a comment and I'll correct it so that the answer is complete.

Comment: Thanks very much, my friend!

Comment: I just had to add an initialization between load and resize (      $('#extruderLeft').openMbExtruder(true);
      $('.extruder.left .flap').css('display','none');
      $('.site_wrapper').css('padding-left','0'); )
so that the sidebar would come up initially on larger screens (there's probably a better way to do that)

Comment: @RationalRabbit A little bit against my earlier advice, but in this case try if you can use `document.ready` instead of `window.load`, see if it works without a problem. The reason for this is, because you first 'show' that sidebar and then immediately hide it again, if you use `document.ready` there's a smaller change the user will actually see all that happening.

Comment: Actually, window.load works better than document.ready. document.ready causes a slight screen blip, whereas window.load slides the sidebar in from the left, giving it an animation effect rather than what seems like a hiccup. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Oh - I see what you mean - on smaller screen sizes it displays as you describe. However, it will do the same - whether document.ready or window.load is used, unless I remove the initial code between load and resize, as I mentioned above. But then, the sidebar will not initially display at larger screen sizes. So I ended up doing this (outline).

Comment: (didn't realize there was a time limit on edits) - (continued)  document.ready; window.resize; if(window.width < 752), {tab}; else {sidebar}; resize(); if(window.width > 751) {sidebar]}

Comment: @RationalRabbit Can't you just have the sidebar already showing at startup, I mean by means of HTML and CSS, without having to use JS? And then the resize-function we initially came up with should do the trick of hiding it on startup if necessary, right? And after that the resize-function should work as expected on manual resize. Or is that not possible due to the use of MB Extruder?

Comment: Open and close requires the js file. Yes, I could do that, but, in effect, I would have to replace the HTML sidebar div, and the contents of the div are a calendar that searches a db table for active dates which display, when selected, in another div and below that, displays a list of programs that display in another div, the list pulls keywords from the programs in the second right hand div so the user can filter those results. If using CSS originally, I don't think I Could do that without querying twice.

Comment: Originally, I tried using jQuery to just change the ID of the sidebar / tab div, but it becomes a chicken and egg thing.