# need to click twice to trigger .click event on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

below is my jquery code for a dropdown menu :

```
$(function(){

    $(".toggleMenu").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".menu").toggle();
});

    var ww = document.body.clientWidth;
    if (ww < 1000) {
        $(".toggleMenu").css("display", "inline-block");
        $(".menu").hide();
        $(".menu ul li a").click(function() {
            $(this).parent("li").toggleClass('hover');
        });
    } else {
        $(".toggleMenu").css("display", "none");
        $(".menu li").hover(function() {
            $(this).addClass('hover');
        }, function() {
            $(this).removeClass('hover');
        });
    }

})
```

what i am trying to do is add the class "hover" to the "li" of the clicked "a" so that the drop down menu works properly on mobile deivices(device with less than 1000px in my case). but with the code above, i need to click twice to any "a" element for the dropdown to apper, as far as i am concerned when i click on "a" element, the class "hover" should be added to its parent "li" element and the hidden "ul" under it should be shown(because i have written the css in that manner) but at the moment i should click on the "a" element two times(not double click).The html structure is like:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a></a>
    <ul>
     <li><a></a></li>
     <li><a></a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Track the amount of times an element has been clicked would be the route here, if you're against dblClick

Comment: Are you saying you have to double click now but that's an error? Or you'd like it to require double click?

Comment: That isn't happening here. I only click once (when the screen width is < 1000px) and it toggles the hover class as expected https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XgbgrQ do you have some sort of hover CSS on the `li` or something that you didn't include? that might make you have to click the link twice for the link action to happen.

Comment: **Sidenotes:** **(1)** Move your `click` and `hover` handlers out of the if-clauses and on the same level as the other click-handler, otherwise they will be added again and again creating a shitload of duplicate handlers. **(2)** Inside your if-clause put an extra if-clause to check the `display` state, otherwise the if-clause is executed on every resize whether the menu is already hidden or not. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44379141/3407923) and my comments and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44399107/3407923).

Comment: Aside from that, you need to supply a working code snippet for us to fiddle around with. Add the CSS and the classes to the HTML so that your code here works and we can see the problem in action.